# Android Admob There was a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0

Tags: android, admob

I have an app in the play store for 2 years now, everything was working fine until today, Ads stopped showing (Admob) for no reason.. I've googled the issue, and didn't find anyone facing the same issue.

In the other hand, my other applications still getting ads.

So this is what i know :

- My app didn't get suspended ( still having access to it in the console)
- Admob account not suspended, didn't receive any email.
- getting this error : There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
- Everything is updated ( gradle, play services..)

Does anyone had this issue?

Comment: @Anantham don't exist

Comment: Finally I contacted the AdMob team, and they told me that ads were disabled in my app because i misplaced interstitial ads.. so I corrected the bugs, updated the app, filed an appeal and they reserved ads to my app.

Comment: how to contact the admob team? just through their forum?

Comment: i am faceing same problem? now my ads was working fine until last day. so how did you contacted admob team?